# Choosing increasing numbers from a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the solution to this question: Select numbers uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, one after the other, as long as they keep decreasing; stop selecting when you obtain a number that is greater than the previous you selected. On average, how many numbers have you selected?

I know we would have to use law of total expectation as follows:

$E[X] = E[X|Y>X]*P(Y>X) + E[X|Y<X]*P(Y<X)$, where $X$ is the first number drawn and $Y$ is the second number. However, in the solution for this question they say the above equation is equal to:
$E[X] = 1*(1-x) + \int_0^x{(E[Y]+1)*f(y)dy}$. I don't understand why they are taking $P(Y<X)$ as the PDF of $Y$ rather than just $P(Y<X) = X$ or I'm wondering if my initial law of total expectation equation is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand neither what you nor what they are trying to do – I'd solve this problem like this (where $N$ is the number of numbers selected):

$$E[N]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(N=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N\ge n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(n-1)!}=\mathrm e\;,$$

where the probability $P(N\ge n)=1/(n-1)!$ follows because there are $(n-1)!$ equiprobable ways in which the first $n-1$ numbers can be ordered and exactly one of these leads to an $n$-th number being selected.

Comment: @jorikie Can I ask why is ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(N=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N\ge n)}$?

Comment: @Jojo: Picture the sum as rectangles of height $n$ and width $P(N=n)$, placed next to each other on a common baseline; then instead regard the same area as made up of rectangles of height $1$ and width $P(N\ge n)$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would you mind if I extended this question here? I was just wondering, what would be the expected value of the smallest number we have selected?

Comment: @Jojo: We have $P(N=n)=\frac1{(n-1)!}-\frac1{n!}$, and the expected value of the smallest number under the condition $N=n$ is $1/(n+1)$, so the unconditional expected value of the smallest number is

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{(n-1)!}-\frac1{n!}\right)\frac1{n+1}= \frac12-\left(\mathrm e-\frac52\right)=3-\mathrm e\approx0.2817\;.$$

I haven't checked this, but it sounds reasonable. If you want a more thorough explanation, I think it would be preferable if you post a new question about it (and link to it here in case others are interested).